Could a civilisation develop spaceflight by artillery before developing orbit-capable rockets?
Was developing a civilisation that developed spaceflight of sorts, before they developed rockets capable of putting things into orbit from the planet surface, by having a honking great mortar/railgun blast things into orbit, and became curious about whether this would be plausible, or if it would be impossible, either because the equipment/astronauts would be destroyed by the force of launch, there aren't materials to take that kind of force, or it's simply not feasible to do it that way, when they can just fit everything into a big engine.

OP specified no rockets available.

@Antares SpinLaunch only accelerates the rocket to about 2 km/s. The rocket itself has to handle about 7 km/s to get to orbit, and so must be a nearly orbit-capable rocket on its own, which is why it's a full two-stage rocket. The sling only makes the first stage smaller.

@ChristopherJamesHuff You're right! I mixed up the km/s and km/h and deduced that the rocket only needs to give "the last nudge" into orbit. Thanks for pointing this out!

@Antares their marketing really wants people to think the sling does more than it really does, and I'm not convinced their leadership understands the difference. I don't know how many times I've seen it suggested that the rocket just does a "final nudge".

on a planet much smaller than earth maybe.

@L.Dutch: OP specified no rockets capable of putting things into orbit from the planet's surface available.  That doesn't rule out that they could have small, low-thrust/low-ISP rockets, useable for things like circularizing the orbit of a gun-launched spaceprobe but useless for launching to orbit from the surface.

From my answer to this relevant question: "Jules Verne might have been the first to suggest sending a shell (e.g., from the barrel of a gun) into space.  Space.SE answered the question of whether or not that was plausible.  Their conclusion was if... if... you could scale the physics, it would take over 14,000 Kg of gunpowder, and the g-force would turn humans into a thin pink paste on the back of the capsule."

Note that OP said "a civilization" not "a civilization on Earth". Depending on gravity and atmospheric density this problem could be a lot easier than current answers are assuming.

There is that spin launcher thing

I am a bit surprised Gerald Bull's cannon designs have not been mentioned by the answers (as I glean thru them). Physically gun launch to space is always possible. That should not be the center of the question for an answer. The more prevalent issue is why didnt any of the spacing faring nations choose this route and preferred the engineering and economic challenges from using rockets instead, and what alt historical/fantastical settings would change that calculus.

Manned or biological creature - NO unless able to tolerate 10's of thousand of Gs acceleration. || Unmanned - YES but you MUST have an orbit circularising boost - optimally at the apogee/top of orbit to bring up the perigee/bottom of orbit. || this could be a rocket OR backwards facing gun. || Total delta V needed on earth is about 5 miles per second. || Air losses are severe uness very very very well designed.

Yes with slight modifications. The existing 'no' answers are mostly wrong.
If you want those things to not be smashed into a fine powder before launch, you're going to need a very long acceleration, not one big boom, as Vesper correctly notes. You could do this without a rocket by using a very long tube with timed sequential explosions and a frictionless (magnetically levitated) projectile, or, much more efficiently, a very long railgun or coilgun.
At this point you're probably still thinking of something that looks like a gun, but this is wrong. You want a roughly 11km/s boost, and $v^2 = 2ad$, where v is the desired boost, a is acceleration, and d is distance traveled. We want astronauts who aren't dead at the end, so let's set $a = 90m/s^2$, about 9 gravities. Solve for $d=670km$. (About a 2 minute boost, with $t = \sqrt{2d/a}$))
Of course you can't build a 670km tall tower or a 670km deep pit. But you can build a 670km long very straight, very flat horizontal tunnel, if you really want to, evacuate all the air out of it, and turn the whole thing into a magnetic accelerator.
This will of course not point you straight up, like a rocket launch. This is irrelevant. All you need to do to get into orbit is to have enough energy and miss the planet on the way there.
Rockets do this with an initial vertical launch because of the structural engineering constraints of rocketry: if you tried to launch a rocket at a low angle, it would (a) fall like a rock and then explode or (b) break in half under the torque of supporting itself from one end, explode, and then fall like a rock. And since the rocket carries all of its energy with it in the fuel tanks, it doesn't even stand to gain anything by trying.
A projectile does not carry its energy with it, the energy is supplied by the launcher. So the opposite is the case: the projectile doesn't stand to gain anything by aiming up any higher than is necessary to miss the horizon on the way to space.
An additional non-problem which may seem like a problem is achieving a lasting orbit instead of a goodbye-forever escape trajectory. This can be handled with minute tuning of launch timing and launch velocity (you don't actually need or want to have quite escape velocity). You can further adjust your orbit by boosting with small rockets, solar or laser sails, etc which are packaged into the launch projectile. If you have a natural satellite like Earth's moon, it opens up the option of crazy computer calculus orbits instead of just various modified ellipses.
The actual problems to solve are:
1: Building and powering the thing. We could probably do it with modern technology and infrastructure if we really, really wanted to, but it would be the most expensive engineering project in history by a few orders of magnitude. Adding cheap, reliable fusion power and some engineering advances under the hood would help a lot towards making this the sort of thing that one wealthy state could achieve on its own.
2: There's air in the way. You're going to want the launch point to be in as close to vacuum as possible. A high mountain would help - not for gravitational potential energy by being higher or some kind of upward angled ramp, but just to be where the air is thinner. You still will need a projectile that's built for extreme heat (the air in front of the projectile will be meteor-hot from compression) and excellent aerodynamics (or it'll tear itself apart), and you also need to pay for all the energy the projectile is dumping into heating the air between the tip of the gun and hard vacuum.
3: related to 1, this is a colossal undertaking that requires modern or better technology and infrastructure, and therefore it's implausible that it would be done by anybody who couldn't figure out how to launch rockets the way that we do. Fortunately, this is an easy fix if you're not limited to planet Earth: just turn up the gravity while keeping air pressure at sea level the same. If we pump up the size of the planet by about 1.5x bigger radius and 4x bigger mass, we roughly double escape velocity and slightly less than double surface gravity. Human-like beings could live somewhere like that, but they'd be pretty close to stuck there forever if they needed to use chemical rockets. But if we use a linear accelerator, we need a 4x longer launch tube, and then we're good to go.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No matter how you build your artillery, your perigee will always be at the same height as  muzzle. To raise your perigee above the atmosphere, you need to either have your muzzle outside of the atmosphere (hahahahha) or you need to boost your vehicle at or near the apogee (without rockets?). Basic orbital mech you would learn on any playthrough of KSP.

"...This will of course not point you straight up, like a rocket launch..." Straight up would be completely the wrong direction. A circular orbit is parallel to the ground. Horizontal is the way to go. Conventional rocket launches start out vertically because (A) they can, and (B) there's an advantage to getting up out of the densest air (the air closest to the ground) as quickly as possible. But soon, they must roll over and point more or less parallel to the ground because most of their fuel is needed to build up horizontal, orbital velocity, and not so much of it for gaining altitude.

You can't put things into orbit by artillery.
Anything you shot with a cannon will enter a path around Earth, and that path will cross Earth either:

never more, because you shot it faster than Earth escape velocity (11 km/s)
one more time in the point of impact, which will be either your target if you are an old school artillery adept or yourself if you have carefully chosen the velocity to kill yourself in a spectacular way.

Sending things into orbit requires the ability to:

go really fast (and you might have this with artillery)
change velocity in flight to adjust the path and make it become an ellipse completely outside the hard surface of Earth

Changing velocity in flight requires rockets or other engines.


The second option will be an elliptical orbit, that will be mostly not yourself but a point somewhere on the other side of the Earth. 2. You don't count with air drag, which will be quite a big one with this speed. Actually it will be so big that a working artillery launch would look like a nuclear bomb. However, air drag will affect the launched object on a continuous path, not as a momentarily impulse transfer, making its net result of a feasible orbit a not total impossibility. The total impossibility is to accelerate the thing to 11km/s (+ tremendous air drag loss) on a railgun.


What could maybe work, if there is already some way to go above the most of the atmosphere even before launch. I imagine a long (at least 300km) long railgun, inside a vacuum tube. Its endpoint must be, for example, on a 2km high tower built on a 8km heigh mountain spike, close to the equator. The whole thing should look like a needle and the sonic boom of the launch could be heard (and might be visible) from very, very far away. I think the main reason, why it is not even planned, that Musk can make reusable things from a lot lesser money.

"Sending things into orbit requires the ability to: change velocity .. adjust the path" How about if the "bullet" is at least in part a smaller "gun" (or has one) that can be adjusted to aim different directions, or several solid mounted pointing different directions, you've got guns they're allowed, fired with powder and with or without shot, as capable in its own way of altering trajectory as a "rocket" in this situation .. Jules Vern with extra bells and whistles tacked on.

If you shot it at the right angle, you could get a gravity assist off the Moon (if any) to help circularize your orbit.

It's worth mentioning though that the delta-v required to circularise an orbit is tiny compared to the energy needed to reach orbital velocity in the first place. Hence it could be done with a comparatively primitive, inefficient rocket design with a comparatively small amount of fuel - the tech needed for that is far less than the tech needed to get to orbit.

@Pelinore Then you essentially just have a rocket on the spacecraft, except instead of your reaction mass being burned hydrazine or w/e, its gunpowder smoke and/or a projectile.

@GraySheep you can use aerodynamics to alter your orbit, but you can't use them to reach a stable orbit, because once again, the last place your craft received an impulse must have been in the atmosphere.  You may be able to get a few complete orbits in that way, but it -will- decay and come back down relatively quickly.

Re "Kill yourself spectacularly": https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227878/53963

@Ryan_L hence my quote marks around the words gun and rocket ;) once you have one you functionally have both from an 'every action has an equal and opposite' perspective .. depending on how you use it .. the only difference is where the fuel is (part of the intended projectile or external to it) and that one uses all its fuel in one go while the other normally burns it incrementally, and then you get things like project Orion that blur that second line, so it's really just where the fuel is.

@Ryan_L Probably yes, although I did not calculate it. Important factor is that also the atmospheric density is decreasig continuously, smoothly. In some sense, even the LEO satellites are orbiting in the upper atmosphere. It depends on the numbers, where is the best possible orbit reachable on this way. I do not know. But the whole question is hyphothetical as 25mach in the surface is totally impossible, probably it is impossible even at 10km height (note what happened to the Columbia space shuttle in 60km height).

@Ryan_L Btw, even if we are already an orbit, it does not matter, how bad orbit, we can use ion propulsion. The hard thing is to get to orbit. And ion propulsion is much more efficient. Imagine a micro-fusion drive capable to fuse some grams of deuterium in an hour, it would be already enough to repair the orbit of such a launch. Result would be that we could go into space without huge tanks filled with the best fuels.

Balistic space flight has been part of science fiction culture since 1865.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_Earth_to_the_Moon
Wikipedia actually has a great breakdown of the challenges, and efforts in that direction. Yes, humans would be turned to paste from ballistic acceleration. There have been numerous efforts at putting hardware into orbit, but thus far, the closest we've come is sub-orbital flight.
The most promising effort in that direction involves using a centrifuge to fling things. Even at a couple orders of magnitude less acceleration, 500-ish G's would still kill humans, but there's a decent chance that they'll be able to throw something that can produce its own thrust, and hardened electronics could survive.
Overall, however, I can't imagine anything built before 1950 surviving that kind of treatment and remaining functional. Definitely not people.

"can't imagine anything built before 1950 surviving that kind of treatment and remaining functional. Definitely not people" true, your average OAP is going too have a rough time of it ;)

You can accelerate to 7.8km/s with 10g in 78 seconds on a 320km long rail. 10g for 78 seconds is well survivable for a trained guy, although he likely won't smile. Problem is that the lower atmosphere behaves like a beton wall in that speed. 25 mach... another problem is that you need actually much more than 7.8km/s, you also need the kinetical energy to elevate to at least 300km height, and also to win the drag. This late is probably impossible. Even the 10mach scramjets went on 10-20km heigh, looked like a needle, and glowed yellow in seconds.

@GraySheep, Have you calculated how high a tower you'd need to build to support a 320km long coil gun, given curvature of the Earth? Rocketry is easier, or we'd have done it already.

Yes, rocketry is much easier. At least it looks now so. Although it should be build only once, and then it could make a launch in maybe 2 minutes. On the first part of the rail, the speed would not be so big, and its real optimal trajectory would need likely a more elaborated calculation. I am thinking on a 2km heigh frame, built on a 8km heigh mountain top. It could look like a huge ski jumping sort. I think, only the building would cost maybe between 10-50billion or yet much more. And, for a 25mach vacuum coil gun, there is not even any similar technology, it should be first developed.

Btw, in the case of the Moon, the escape velocity is only 5mach, there is no atmosphere, and it is tidally locked to the Earth.  I think, the Moon could have a fixed position for an orbital railgun system with what you can reach Earth any time. Heinlein has written a story, "Moon is a harsh mistress", about the independence war of the first Moon colony. They use such a coil gun as a weapon to bombard the Earth.

@GraySheep, Oh, yes. Railguns on the Moon will be a given, but I expect serious resistance against one that could be pointed at the Earth. :) I suspect that this plan is the real motivation behind Hyperloop.

@RobertRapplean: coil gun 320 km long would need to be 150 feet high at the terminal end.  Height of the structure is not a problem…

@jmoreno, Could you check your math? At the equator 320 kilometers is 2.88 degrees of longitude. A little trig tells me that a triangle with that hypotenuse and 2.88 degrees for angle A should have an opposing side around 4 km.

Artillery ammunition consists of a cylindrical cartridge case containing a propelling charge, with an opening at one end obstructed by a shell.
If the shell is removed and the cartridge is turned upside down, it becomes a solid rocket booster.
Both slow rate burning and exploding nature of black powder have been experimented as soon as black powder or gunpowder has been invented; firework rockets and guns may have arrived at the same time.
A civilization having mastered artillery would most likely develop an artillery based spaceflight program by using the slow burning nature of the propellant they already use to explosively propel bullets or shells.
Instead of having the bullet as a payload, cartridge becomes the payload.

If explosions are mandatory for this question of achieving spaceflight using artillery technology, this Space Exploration SE Q&A might be useful and is roughly about doing that, even if no shells or bullets are used:
Could a Project like Orion be built today with non nuclear weapons?

No
The best "space flight" you can achieve with artillery is a sort of an ICBM (unguided). The reason is that in order to reach circular orbit the space ship has to accelerate after reaching the required altitude, which is impossible with artillery propulsion. And shooting up a cannon with the spaceship will break the cannon - it's a pretty accurate machinery in itself to survive cannonball accelerations unscathed.

The thing being launched can have engines to adjust it after launch, they're just not powerful enough to get it off the ground to begin with (hence the gargantuan cannon/railgun to do that part).

Any engine is a device that's not tolerant to high accelerations caused by firing a cannon. In case you limit them to some dozens of Gs, you're no longer firing a cannon as explosive stuff does not have capability to accelerate something for that long. BTW in order to make an ICBM, you'll need some serious blast that would have the exhaust speed of ~6 km/s, there seem to be substances that burn this fast, but consider the acceleration first before adding stuff to your "spaceship".

probably not. Gun or rapid launch spaceflight has been dismissed as silly namely because the G-forces from standstill to launch are far greater than rockets. Peak acceleration of a howitzer is 15,000 G which would kill any person. The record highest survived G forces was approximately 47.


Only if it is a lower than Earth gravity planet
While the orbital velocity around an Earth sized planet is 7.8 km/s. Orbiting a smaller planet or moon would be much easier.  For example, if your civilization were on a planet about the size of Luna, it would only need a muzzle velocity of ~1.6 km/s.  Luckily for your civilization, such cannons were first developed around the time of the space race like the T-12 anti-tank gun.  If you planet were Luna sized, then your civilization would have had a lot less incentive to pursue rocketry because the whole reason we started studying rockets was to outrange cannons, but cannons are much cheaper, and your civilization could have pursued high-velocity smooth bore cannons in lue of of rockets to achieve the same goals at a much lower cost.
You will not be able to put a man into space with such a cannon due to acceleration, but satellites would be possible. Just fire a shell up into space, that is fused to fire a secondary charge to change its ballistic path into an orbital path once it achieves its apogee.
Eventually you might transition to railguns capable of a human(alien) survivable acceleration, but this will take a few decades since it takes a LOT of power generation to make a railgun that can send a projectile that heavy that fast. While modern railguns can achieve fuel efficiencies almost as good as rockets, space-race era rail guns were much less efficient meaning you'd need somewhere between 7-70 times as much fuel per launch as is required with a rocket, assuming you could make rails that would survive the launch.
So, I don't think you'd fully side-step the rocket age since low gravity also make space rockets way easier, but you would probably see both systems developed in parallel with cannons being using to launch smaller satellites and rockets being reserved for heavy lift vehicles.

I once had the idea that size and thus cost of a rail gun type launch system could be reduced by making the projectile accelerate around a circular track many times until it had enough velocity and then diverting it to a straight launch track.
And I think I later calculated that in a circular launch system by the time the projectile was close to launch speed it would have a centrifugal outward acceleration of only 1 gravity if the circular launch system had a diameter of several hundred kilometers or miles or more.  Thus a circular track instead of a straight track would still be enormous.
Of course physically fit astronauts could handle an acceleration of several gravities for several minutes, thus reducing the size of the circular track considerably.
And sending up unmanned space probes which could handle tens or hundreds or thousands of gravities would require much smaller circular tracks.  So if there is a use for such acceleration hardened unmanned space vehicles, it may be possible to launch them from a track which it is economically feasible to build.
I have a vision of a launch track which goes around an entire planet and the spacecraft travel around the world at least once and possibly many times as they accelerate to launch speed.  Thus they might travel around the world in 80 minutes before launching. Such a system might be more practical around a small moon or asteroid.  And if launching from an airless astronomical object, the problems with atmospheric drag and heating would not be present.
As written above, there would be strong problems with atmospheric drag and heating if a projectile was launched anywhere near sea level on a habitable planet similar to Earth.
Once fusion power generation is developed decades in the future, it might be possible to raise a giant circular launch system many kilometers or miles high, where the the atmosphere will be significantly thinner and the problems with atmospheric drag and heating significantly less.
Possibly the vast circular launch system might be raised by magnetohydrodynamic engines powered by the fusion generators on the launch system - or beaming power from the ground. Or maybe it might be lifted to altitude by countless vast balloons.  Those balloons might have vacuum instead of lifting gas inside, being inflated by electromagnetic mutual repulsion of their sides.
And if the problems of low enough acceleration for humans to survive and atmospheric drag and heating are solved, then the problem will be that the system can only give its projectiles interplanetary velocities and trajectories.  It can't give its projectiles orbital trajectories unless those contain some propulsion method to correct their trajectories to orbital ones once they are above the atmosphere.  Maybe the projectiles headed for orbit could use ion drives to change their paths to orbital ones.
And if manned projectiles are sent to other planets and worlds, how will the projectiles land on them, and return to the planet they came from?
I hope that there are sufficient suggestions to solve those problems, because the Lost in Space franchise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_in_Space# makes me desire a parody with a good reason to be called Tossed in Space.

"orbit by trebuchet"
